# How can I debug an Antlr grammar when I get `no viable alternative at input` error?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Note: I don't want a solution for a specific grammar, that's why I don't quote my conflicting rules here.

I've had this error many times and usually I'm able to solve it, but it requires a static code analysis I.E. me staring at the grammar code until the A-HA moment comes.

I'd like to be able to debug it in some way, maybe the parser can give me a hint of which rules it successfully applied and where did it stall, or any other kind of hint.
Is this possible?

Comment: Set break points in the generated files, and debug (for C# that's normal).

Comment: @LexLi where should I set the breakpoints? when I get `no viable alternative` it means the parser could not apply any of the grammar rules, so no listener methods will be called. I'd need some way to look at the token stream.

Comment: What's the target language of your grammar? I will be surprised that you cannot debug into the generated parser/lexer source code. No, I am not asking you to debug "listener methods".